# Why do I get a "No suitable method found for anonymous " error?

Tags: java, anonymous-types, inner-classes, anonymous

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(varx) {
            new displayFullScreen().setVisible(true);
        } else {
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "dfv"); // this statement gives an error
        }
    }
};
new Thread(r,"full_screen_display").start();
```

The error in the marked line says `"No suitable method found for anonymous (<java.lang.Runnable>,java.lang.String)`"

Why does it so when i have directly written `javax.swing._CLASS_` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `this` in that line refers to the anonymous `Runnable` instance you've created, not the class that surrounds it. You'll need to be more explicit about what `this` you mean in there.

If the enclosing class is named `Foo`, and is a swing `Component`, you should write:

```
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Foo.this, "dfv");
```

See the [Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) docs for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` expects a `Component` as the first argument, but you're passing in `this`, which is a `Runnable` (anonymous).

Answer (score 0):

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29) says:

> parentComponent - determines the Frame in which the dialog is
>   displayed; if null, or if the parentComponent has no Frame, a default
>   Frame is used

`javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "dfv");` will not work as `this` is a `Runnable` which does not inherit from `Component`.
Use this instead:

```
javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "dfv");
```